# QSqlQueryModel returns empty result

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, qt

The code:

```
queryModel = new QSqlQueryModel();
QSqlQuery sql;
QString strSql = "{CALL syllabi_output}";
sql.exec(strSql);
queryModel->setQuery(sql);
ui->tableView_4->setModel(queryModel);
```

Headers are present, but there are no rows.

The stored procedure works correctly in Management Studio (two rows).

Answer (score 0):

The query is a local variable, and gets destructed as soon as it goes out of scope. You likely invoke this in a method or a constructor, so the scope ends swiftly before the view has a chance of doing anything with the query's data. The query model outlives the query, and has no data to offer, thus the view shows up empty.

Instead, you should persist both the model and the query together. For example:

```
class Widget : public QWidget {
  Q_OBJECT
  Widget::Ui ui;
  QSqlQueryModel m_model;
  QSqlQuery m_modelQuery;
  ...
public:
  void runQuery() {
    m_modelQuery.exec(QStringLiteral("{CALL syllabi_output}"));
    m_model.setQuery(m_modelQuery);
    ui.tableView_4->setModel(&m_model);
  }
  ...
};
```

If the query is always simple, and you always wish to exec it right away, you can use the other `setQuery` overload:

```
class Widget : public QWidget {
  Q_OBJECT
  Widget::Ui ui;
  QSqlQueryModel m_model;
  ...
public:
  void runQuery() {
    m_model.setQuery(QStringLiteral("{CALL syllabi_output}"));
    ui.tableView_4->setModel(&m_model);
  }
  ...
};
```

Note that there's no point to storing the `ui` or the query model as a pointer. If you insist on lazily instantiating the query model, you can of course do so:

```
class Widget : public QWidget {
  Q_OBJECT
  Widget::Ui ui;
  QPointer<QSqlQueryModel> m_model; // this is a non-owning pointer
  ...
public:
  void runQuery() {
    if (m_model.isNull()) m_model = new QSqlQueryModel(this);
    m_model->setQuery(QStringLiteral("{CALL syllabi_output}"));
    ui.tableView_4->setModel(&m_model);
  }
  ...
};
```

Comment: I changed code as you suggested. Now I create model and query globally in header: 

    `SqlQueryModel queryModel;`
    `QSqlQuery sqlSetTable;`

And do the rest in function:

    `sqlSetTable.exec(QStringLiteral("{CALL syllabi_output}"));`
    `queryModel.setQuery(sqlSetTable);`
    `ui->tableView_4->setModel(&queryModel);`

Now it's not working at all, the headers are not displayed either now. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found this trying to solve a similar problem.  In addition to the variable scoping mentioned by Kubar, there are some other Qt and SQL Server issues.

- `QSqlQueryModel` can only be used with forward-only queries
- Forward only for a query is determined by the database driver. `setForwardOnly(false)` is only a suggestion
- By default, SQL Server stored procedures may return multiple (intermediate) result sets.

[This answer from Qt Forum](https://forum.qt.io/topic/75378/qsqltablemodel-only-fetching-table-headers-with-names-and-no-data-from-table-qodbc/17) goes into more detail.